# Bubble of air in resistor follows $ r^{3}$ law?

Tags: electrical-resistance, simulations, conductors

I used a program to simulate the resistance of a resistor when a small bubble (compared to size of the resistor) of air of radius $r$ was placed inside the resistor, as $r$ increased.

I plotted the resistance of the resistor versus radius $r$ and it seems to follow perfectly a 3rd degree polynomial. I was wondering if this law has been proven or whether it is easy to derive or whether it is wrong?

Comment: You need to tell us more about your model.  How did you simulate the resistor?

Comment: I used COMSOL multiphysics which uses the finite element method.

Comment: That's a start.  But how did you model the resistor itself?  As a network of short resistive wires, or something else?  And by "bubble" to you mean a volume void of whatever makes up the bulk of your resistor?

Comment: Its a physical model of a resistor with electrode plates and filled with a medium with certain conductivity and permittivity, the program then solves maxwell equations to get the resistance. The cavity itself is air and non-conductive.

Comment: I have 30 points and a 3rd degree polyonimal that fits them well, I dont know what to infer from this statement? If we choose just 4 points spread out, its not impressive because we have 4 parameters and the rest of the points just lie inbetween,

Comment: You must have set up your simulation somehow.  You've told me the tool you used, and something about the results, but you haven't yet told me how you set things up.  How do you represent the resistor in your setup?  You also don't tell us if your resistance is going up or down.

Comment: One way to model a bulk resistor might be as a dense network of short resistive wires all connected to each other in a complicated mesh.  That's the kind of thing I'm looking for.  How do you mathematically "construct" your resistor.

Comment: See the fourth comment in this thread. Resistance is ofcourse going up. What do you mean represent? Could you clarify your question? I dont understand how the details of the program matters at all. Its a program which gives realistic results thats all you need to know.

Comment: You can get an idea of what to expect by considering a simpler idealized model.  Think of the resistor as a bar with a fixed rectangular cross-section.  The cross section is fully filled by a number of smaller rectangles.  Say three of them arranged like a sandwich.  Allow the areas to vary while keeping the total area constant.  Allow the center one to have a void of variable length.  You can use the elementary analysis of resistors and resistivity to calculate how the resistance of the assembly varies as the void gets larger in length and area.  Your COMSOL calc should yield similar behavior

Comment: Hmmm...  Now I see what you mean by "fourth comment".   For some reason, that comment was not showing up earlier.  I see it now.

Comment: Uh ... *you* are asking the question.  It's not up to you to decided what I need to know!

Comment: BTW,  the answers to [the other question you asked](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273241/5739)  give more detail on the idealized model I suggested.   Curious:  which came first, the COMSOL question or the "cavity" question?   Either way, it's a great idea to approach the problem in these two different ways!

Comment: *"I plotted the resistance of the resistor versus radius and it seems to follow perfectly a 3rd degree polynomial."* All this is telling you is that $R=a_0+a_1r+a_2r^2+a_3r^3$ fits the data quite well.  This is just curve-fitting, not hypothesis testing. A quartic or quintic will do even better. And unless $a_0=a_1=a_2=0$ this is not saying the same as your title, that $R=ar^3$.

Comment: But I agree with garyp : it is a good question, and an excellent idea to approach it from two angles - theory in the other Qn and simulation in this. It would be very helpful to see your results and more detail of your simulation - eg shape and dimensions of resistor, size and position of cavity, graph or table of results.

Answer (score 4):

A small bubble will reduce the cross sectional area of the resistor for a short distance. The "effective area" will be $A_0 - \pi r^2$, and this reduced area will be effective for a length "that scales with $r$".

[image]

The result is a change in resistance that, for small $r$, will look like (thanks Sammy Gerbil for pointing out an error in an earlier version... )

$$\Delta R \propto \frac{r}{A_0 - \pi r^2}$$

When $\pi r^2 << A_0$, we can rewrite this as

$$\begin{align}\Delta R &\propto \frac{r}{A_0}\frac{1}{1 - \frac{\pi r^2}{A_0}}\\
&\approx \frac{r}{A_0}\left(1 + \frac{\pi r^2}{A_0}\right)\
\end{align}$$

So it seems to me there would be both a linear, and a cubic, term in the change in resistance. Is that the kind of polynomial you are seeing?

Comment: Since $R=\rho L/A$ shouldn't that be $\Delta R \propto r/(A_0-\pi r^2)$? Still gives linear and cubic terms, though, for small $r$.

Comment: @sammygerbil - you are right, I was being sloppy. Think it's fixed now - result is still a cubic (but of course the resistance is now shown as going up, which is correct).

Comment: reallly good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This *may* be relevant and **should be a comment** but too long (also do not know how to include a figure in a comment): If you look at a sphere of radius $r$ and resistivity $\rho$ determine the resistance between the points A and B ( see the figure) as follows:[image]

The resistance of the annulus of thickness $dl$ is $dR = \frac{\rho dl}{\pi L^2}$, where $L^2 + (l-r)^2 = r^2$. This gives $$dR = \frac{\rho}{\pi}\frac{dl}{r^2 - (l-r)^2} = \frac{\rho}{\pi}\frac{dl}{2lr - l^2}$$ so I was expecting the total resistance would be given as the sum of the separate resistances of the shells $R =  \frac{\rho}{\pi} \int^{2r}_0\frac{dl}{2lr - l^2} = \frac{\rho}{\pi r} \int^2_0 \frac{dx}{2x - x^2}$. Unfortunately, this appears to diverge, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

If you mutliply all lengths of a resistor by $L$, the resistance goes as $\frac{R_0}{L}$. So consider a cubical resistor centered on the bubble which scales, in parallel with a O shaped resistor with area $A_0-L^2$. This you can use to find the asymptotics.