# Removing a cavity from inside a resistor

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance

Suppose we have a resistor of resistance R.
We build a new one by removing a cavity A from inside it, and this new resistor has resistance $R_A$. This cavity can be a sphere or similar region.
We then build a third one by not removing region A but by removing another cavity B from inside a resistor like the original, and this new resistor has resistance $R_B$. We also have that A and B are disjoint regions.
We now build a fourth one by removing both region A and B from inside a resistor like the original, and this gives resistance $R_{AB}$.

My question is, is there any (very) approximate relationship $f(R,R_A,R_B)=R_{AB}$ ?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please edit the question and mention how resistor B is being created. Are you removing remove a part of the resistor A or that of the old resistor or of a completely new resistor?

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about this a little. If you remove a serial slice, you can almost think of a resistor as a sequence of serial resistors. Let's make it out of 3 slices:

$$R=R_x+R_y+R_z$$
now for A case, replace $R_y$ by $R_y'$ (bigger resistance because this slice has a cavity now), and for B, replace $R_z$:

$$R_A=R_x+R_y'+R_z$$
$$R_B=R_x+R_y+R_z'$$

Now we seek
$$R_{AB}=R_x+R_y'+R_z'=R_A+R_B-R$$
This will work reasonably well if the cavities don't overlap, and they are far enough apart, so that curving current around one cavity doesn't affect the current flow around the other cavity.

Now think about the case where the holes are in parallel. There, you have
$$\frac1{R_{AB}}=\frac1{R_A}+\frac1{R_B}-\frac1{R}$$

This is not quite the same, so when does which of them apply? Which approximation is better? That we can partition the resistor into parts with cavities and parts without in parallel or serially? This depends on the shape and position of the holes. There are certainly cases where none of the above apply (if the holes overlap a little both in longitudinal and transverse projection, or if the holes are of strange shapes).

If the holes are small and far apart, both approximations should give approximately the same result, as they are just two different types of averaging (arithmetic and harmonic average). This ultimately gives you a very good approximation of the real result - compute both averages and approximate the error with the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I shall assume that you are talking about a carbon resistor. A carbon resistor can be treated as a wire with high specific resistance (resistivity).

Hence, the popular wire resistance formula will work,

$$R = \rho \frac{l}{A}$$

where $\rho$ is the specific resistance, $l$ is the length of the wire and $A$ is the area of the cross-section of the wire.

If you remove a section of the resistor of area $A_1$, the resistance of the resistor will change as follows

$R = \rho \frac{l}{A - A_1}$

The resistance of the resistor $R_A$ will be,

$R_A = \rho \frac{l}{A_1}$

Similarly, you can do the same for resistor B.

You can now solve for a relation between the resistances.

*The question is unclear as of now. I am not quite sure if you are removing a part of resistor to make resistor A then remove another part of the resistor A or remove it from the old resistor or a completely new resistor*

Comment: I think the "cavity" is not necessarily a uniform cross-section of the resistor.

Comment: @sammygerbil Yes you are right. Anyway not much change to be done to the answer. Just a few integrals will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your resistor $R$ is actually three resistors in parallel:

1. The region which lies within the cavity $A$.
2. The region which lies within the cavity $B$.
3. The region which lies within neither $A$ nor $B$.

$R$ is $R_1$ and $R_2$ and $R_3$ in parallel.

$R_A$ is $R_2$ and $R_3$ in parallel.

$R_B$ is $R_1$ and $R_3$ in parallel.

$R_{AB}$ is $R_3$ on its own.

From here, you can work it out for yourself.

- $R$ and $R_A$ will, with appropriate (and simple) algebra, give you the value of $R_1$.
- $R$ and $R_B$ will, with appropriate (and simple) algebra, give you the value of $R_2$.
- $R$ and $R_1$ and $R_2$ will, with appropriate (and simple) algebra, give you the value of $R_3$ (which equals $R_{AB}$).
- So will $R_A$ and $R_2$.
- So will $R_B$ and $R_1$.

The fact that you have three ways of getting to the same answer means that you can confirm your calculations by using all three methods. If the answers are different, you have gone wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer must be "no".

Here is a simple thought process: cavity A occupies one half of the resistor's cross section; cavity B occupies the other half. If you take away the material of both A and B you will have an open circuit.